# facebook page tab application request

Tags: javascript, facebook, apprequests

I have a application running in a page tab
when in my flow i ask the user to send his friends an app request
"my friend" gets the request but when he clicks the request he is brought to the app standalone , not the app running in the page tab

so i thought i can enter a redirect_uri and i put there the link of the page tab application
but then facebook complains

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirect_url must be derived from your site URL, callback URL, etc (something your app 'owns')
Redirect them to a page on your server and then bounce them back to the page tab if you need to for some reason

Comment: is there any method then to transfer data with that redirect to the page tab?

Comment: Anything in the `app_data` GET parameter in your request to the page tab URL will be passed to your app in the `signed_request` - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ (last section) for more info

Answer (score 2):

I thumbs-up Igy's answer... which worked (in the end) for me.
Here are some DETAILS, in case my specific solution throws some light on yours.

In my app definition, i have

```
Page Tab URL: http://tangolausanne.ch/test/app_pagetab/index.php
Site URL:     http://tangolausanne.ch/
```

Then I prepared a login url like this:

```
$params = array(
      'scope' => '',
      // this fails: 
      //'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.facebook.com/tangolausannepage/app_135958839864443'

      //this works
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://tangolausanne.ch/test/app_pagetab/post_oauth.php'
    );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

And later in the index.php of the app_pagetab/index.php, I have this:

```
<a target="_top" href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Continue (login)...</a>
```

Finally, I created a post_oath.php with the following in it:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/tangolausannepage/app_135958839864443");
exit;
?>
```

So when non-auth'd facebook users it my tab-app on http://www.facebook.com/tangolausannepage (the big red button) they get the login link, followed by the oauth, followed by a fast page redirection back to the app inside the pagetab on facebook. Cosmetically it seems to work for the moment. Good luck to you.

shawn